# Image inside Table overlaps with navigation list item while scrolling

Tags: html, css

[image]. See the attached screen shot. Am developing a small website using HTML, CSS3, Javascript For a requirement, i added an image inside a table and it displays properly without any issues. But while scrolling it overlaps with the top fixed Navigation bar (UL > LI elements packed horizontally). Am new to HTML and would like to know is there any Z-Property to push the image behind the navigation bar menu.

HTML Code:

```
<table class="color-menu-content-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table class="color-menu-content-table">
    <tbody>
        text content goes here
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:center;">
    **<img src="myglobe.jpg" style="border-radius:8px;opacity:0.9;">**
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
myglobe.jpg image is overlapping

CSS3 Code:
.color-menu-content-table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: double;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid green;
    vertical-align: middle;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: behind the image, there are list items - "Title 3 HERE", "Title 4 HERE", "Title 5 HERE". Am testing in Mozilla latest version.

Answer (score 0):

z-index 1 should be added to the Parent div of Header which is having list items - "Title 3 HERE", "Title 4 HERE", "Title 5 HERE".